# Multiparty read uploaded file content

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

How can I get uploaded file content using multiparty in node.js? I don't need temp file, I need to redirect all stream into Google Cloud Storage in order to save the file content, but I can't find the way to get this content with events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. We need to use part stream a subscribe to standard streams events, like, `data` and `end` in order to receive file's data.

```
part.on("data", chunk => {
    writeStream.write(chunk);
});

part.on("end", chunk => {
    writeStream.end(chunk);
});
```

writeStream - is a another stream where you want to put your data. In my case that was Google Cloud Storage file PUT request via signedUrl.
part - is a part object of a form `part` event